# Search for the position of an element in a array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

There is this array:

```
$my_array = array("One","two","four");
```

I need to search for an element and get its position back?

I.e: Searching for "four" would return 2

Comment: thank you for the credits. I took the liberty and upvoted the other two answers as well, since Jason posted his almost simultaneously with me and basically the same content (I think he was a few seconds earlier), and Srinis answer because it adds important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP provides a built-in function for this purpose: [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
array_search('four', $my_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

remember array_search() will return the key of the first matching element only. If there are multiple matching elements, you will have to use array_keys() which returns an array of the matching keys.

```
// Using array_search()
$arr = array ( 0 =>"Apple", 1=>"Orange", 2=>"Lime", 3=>"Peach", 4=>"Lime" );
$key = array_search("Lime", $arr);
echo $key; // outputs 2

// Using array_keys()
$keys = array_keys($arr, "Lime");
echo '<pre>',print_r($keys),'</pre';
```

outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
)
1
```